# Check Update Available App Store

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, app-store

Anyone known if exist some way to check if exist one update available on App Store??

I want notify to user the new updates on my application begins...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ATAppUpdater](https://github.com/emotality/ATAppUpdater), it is 1 line, thread-safe and fast. It also have delegate methods if you would like to track user action. Here is an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[ATAppUpdater sharedUpdater] showUpdateWithConfirmation]; // 1 line of code
    /////////////////////// OR ///////////////////////
    [[ATAppUpdater sharedUpdater] showUpdateWithForce]; // 1 line of code

   return YES;
}
```

Delegate methods:

```
- (void)appUpdaterDidShowUpdateDialog;
- (void)appUpdaterUserDidLaunchAppStore;
- (void)appUpdaterUserDidCancel;
```

Comment: Can you share same for swift

Comment: @Muju Someone made a Swift version here: https://github.com/emotality/ATAppUpdater/pull/12/files

Answer (score 62):

You can easily ask the App Store to return your application info:

e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=441252681

In the json response, the `"info"` field is what you're looking for, and you get it updated for free!

[See the official documentation here.](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/)

Comment: Apparently the JSON structure has changed, since it's now in the "version" field.

Comment: you can find the ID of your app in itunes connect. Login, select app and locate the "apple id" row at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Unfortunately your JSON appears not to be available while the app is in development. Also, this is a brittle solution, if Apple changes it mind on the format. I actually prefer (and implemented) the accepted answer. But I'm obviously alone :-)

Comment: I try to use this idea combined with other answers, but it didn't work correctly because the app create a cache for the file and don't check when a new version is released because the file is already cached in the system. I will try to use a solution with Firebase Remote Config.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use a library available on Binpress that does the checking for you. As of this post the library is free.

http://www.binpress.com/c/615/6592

You could also use your own notification message when you push an update rather than using an automated check (available on Binpress and again also free as of this post)

http://www.binpress.com/c/662/6592

NOTE: I am in no way related to or receiving payment/compensation from the Binpress OP

Answer (score 0):

Well YOU know when you have a new update out so you will need to call something to check. I used to have a JSON file hosted which returned a response status showing version number of latest live version. My app would check this URL and see if a new version was available.

Comment: yes, that way is possible, but Don't exist some API call for that? Like the request InAppPurchase Product on In App Purchases...

Comment: I thought this was not allowed by Apple's policy. It might just be "automatic updating" (like Sparkle) but I thought they also meant "no checking for updates" too since they want everything to be updated through their App Store apps. Might want to look into this.

Comment: Knowing that an update is available and directing people to the App Store is perfectly fine. Stopping the use of your app if the user isn't using a certain version, when due to technical or operational reasons, is perfectly fine. Forcing arbitrary updates without due need is not allowed.

Comment: This answer has been posted like some millennia ago but I think this should be the way to do it. People should also explain the down votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library from Github to prompt user if update is available. It's written in swift and has support for 4.2. It has many rules to check and can check with time interval. I think this is what you need

[Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren)