# How do I check if OSX is in the latest version available?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I know that I can't check my OS version as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072974/2700879). Also know that for a simple app I could verify its last version as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6569307/2700879). But I can't see how this last approach could be used to verify if OSX is in its last version, since I don't have an ID that leads me to an OSX info. Is there something like a URL where I could get this kind of info? I was also wondering if there is something like [Windows Update API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). After you ask yourself: The reason why I want to check for it's last version is to inform user that his device could be in a unsafe state, since it doesn't have the last available OSX version. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you find a way to retrieve the most current OSX version, you can compare it with the user's OSX version to see if they are updated.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, a way to get this information.

Comment: Create your own web service which publishes the current version.

Comment: You can do what stuartd said, but if not you can try and parse [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#cite_ref-8) for the latest osx information although the layout may definitely change.