# How to detect an iOS App installed or upgraded?

Tags: ios, installation, upgrade, reinstall

I am developing an application and i need to know whether user installed the app for the first time or upgraded it from the App Store.

How can i detect whether app is installed for the first time or upgraded or re-installed?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can differentiate between the first start after installing the App, the first start after an update and other starts quite easily via saving the latest known version to `standardUserDefaults`. But as far as I know it is not possible do detect a re-install of the App as all App-related data are also removed when the App is deleted from the device.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString* currentVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    NSString* versionOfLastRun = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"VersionOfLastRun"];

    if (versionOfLastRun == nil) {
        // First start after installing the app
    } else if (![versionOfLastRun isEqual:currentVersion]) {
        // App was updated since last run
    } else {
        // nothing changed 
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"VersionOfLastRun"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Maybe storing the version number to keychain will work? I think the data in the keychain is not deleted after the app is uninstalled.

Comment: when do you update the previous version?

Comment: @Nero This is working when I change the Build number, but not the version number. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Sethmr Oh yes, you're right. Thanks for noting this. `CFBundleVersion` actually returns what Xcode calls the Build number, but there's another key `CFBundleShortVersionString` which returns the Version number you enter in the Project Editor.

Comment: The standardized format for Version/Build numbers needs to be actually documented instead of allowing complete and total freedom of use! It was only after seeing those two variables that I realized the Build is basically meant to be an extension onto the Version. I was previously treating it as just an Int with no "." to identify which version.

Comment: Do not use `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` to compare versions! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42552076/1033581

Answer (score 20):

Checkout Swift 3.0 version of code.
Note: Use CFBundleShortVersionString, for checking actual App version checking.

```
func checkAppUpgrade() {
    let currentVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey:     "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
    let versionOfLastRun = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "VersionOfLastRun") as? String

    if versionOfLastRun == nil {
        // First start after installing the app

    } else if versionOfLastRun != currentVersion {
        // App was updated since last run

    } else {
        // nothing changed

    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentVersion, forKey: "VersionOfLastRun")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate :) works like a charm

Comment: This would have required me to set this up from the first version, no? What if there is a version out there and I want to test new install vs update in an upcoming update? @Saggy

Comment: This will fail if you already have a version released without this code and you want to detect the upgrade.

Comment: @Rajashekar : Yes, of course. this code will not work on release on which you don't have this.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3

```
 let currentVersion : String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String

let versionOfLastRun: String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "VersionOfLastRun") as? String

if versionOfLastRun == nil {
     // First start after installing the app
} else if  !(versionOfLastRun?.isEqual(currentVersion))! {
      // App is updated
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(currentVersion, forKey: "VersionOfLastRun")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just for note:**

To obtain localized value of any key you should use `CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "CFBundleShortVersionString" as CFString)`

Answer (score 0):

Please store a version in `NSUserDefaults` (per @Nero's answer) for checking (possible) fresh installs and subsequent updates.

For checking reinstalls (in the case where stored `version == nil`), exploit iOS 11's introduction of [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_the_per_device_data) API which exposes two bits of device specific data which can be set and retrieved by the app, but maintained by Apple and persisted across an uninstall/reinstalls.