# How to check if user visit my iOS app for the first time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

If user is opening application for the first time after downloading it, then I want to show a view controller with tutorial and then go to main application's View Controller.
But if user is already visited app before, then go to Main view controller.

How to implement that check in AppDelegate?

Comment: You could use ```NSUserDefaults``` to store a string value which states if the user has used your app before or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect an iOS App installed or upgraded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118943/how-to-detect-an-ios-app-installed-or-upgraded)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add in your app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"firsttime"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"firsttime"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }

}
```

If condition will check for the key is available in app or not.

If it is not available then it will save it to YES.

You can do as you want.

Comment: what would happen if the user updates application from app store?

Comment: @hariszaman than this data will be lost. User data will be destroyed when you remove the app.

Comment: not removing the app but updating it from app store

Comment: @hariszaman Ok, Please see this question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638766/do-nsuserdefaults-persist-through-an-update-to-an-app-in-the-appstore I am not that person can give that answer :(

Comment: i think for this you should store information on keychain and it is os dependent @hariszaman

Answer (score 2):

I would do that in your main view controller in method `viewWillAppear`. You can use `NSUserDefaults`. Here's an example:

**Swift:**

```
func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
        println("App already launched")
        return true
    } else {
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
        println("App launched first time")
        //Show your tutorial.
        return false
    }
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = [defaults stringForKey:@"isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"];

    if (isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce != nil) {
        NSLog(@"App already launched");
        return true;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"App launched first time");
        [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"];
        //Show your tutorial.
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then run this method in your `viewWillAppear`:

**Swift:**

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce];
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` will be cleared when user will uninstall app.

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag in `NSUserDefaults`. When the user launches the app for the first time, the flag is not set. After checking the status of the flag, if the flag is not set the flag should be set.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **`boolForKey`** and **`setBool`**

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"firsttime"]) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"firsttime"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```