# check app version using deep linking in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, deep-linking, deeplink

How can we check current installed version of our app using deep linking in iOS, so that we can prompt user to upgrade the app.
From safari browser, I want to navigate to app. But as per requirement, I need to check installed version of the app. 
If previous version is installed, we need to prompt user to update the app.

Comment: i guess you can do it in the app itself, and you check the version in : 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

so that you open the application first

Comment: The Appstore app updates the App automatically now so if the user has disabled this feature then they probably know about the fact that their apps are not being updated.

Comment: I think this can only be done in app side instead of the safari side. Or you can tried to set a share cookies in the app storing the version info, then read it in js.

Answer (score 1):

you can get as

The value you set in the Xcode target summary's "Version" field is in here:

ObjC

```
NSString *Currentversion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

To get the **build** number as a `NSString` variable:

```
NSString * CurrentbuildNo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

**For Example**

You could probably do like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    NSString* appIDe = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]; 
    NSURL* getpath = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appIDe]];
    NSData* JSONdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:getpath];
    NSDictionary* JSonDiCt = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONdata options:0 error:nil];

    if ([JSonDiCt[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
        NSString* currentappStoreVersion = JSonDiCt[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersiononApp = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if (![currentappStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersiononApp]){
            NSLog(@"Need to update");
            return YES;
        }else
        {

          //Continue your Work
  }
    }

    return YES;;
}
```

for more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore)