# need to impliment force update functionality in my App ios

Tags: ios, app-store, version

can any one help me how can i impliment alert for force update my iOS app. if new version is available on AppStore where in any Device have old or different version then i want to check if version is different then user update new version from AppStore. and how to get app information for my app.

Comment: Are you using third party or you have  your custom view?

Comment: @JAGAT No i cant want to use any third party library.

Comment: currently i have check version from our WS. but problem is that we have to update all time in WS for new version

Comment: check this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore

Answer (score 0):

You can develop the function by comparing the version of the modern app with the version on the App Store.

```swift
enum VersionError: Error {

    case invalidResponse, invalidBundleInfo

}

class AppStoreCheck {

    static func isUpdateAvailable(completion: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void) throws -> URLSessionDataTask {

        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,

            let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,

            let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,

            let url = URL(string: your appstore url) else {

                throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo

        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            do {

                if let error = error { throw error }

                guard let data = data else { throw VersionError.invalidResponse }

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]

                guard let result = (json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String else {

                    throw VersionError.invalidResponse

                }

                let verInt = NSString.init(string: version).intValue

                let currentVerInt = NSString.init(string: currentVersion).intValue

                completion(verInt > currentVerInt, nil) 

            } catch {

                completion(nil, error)

            }

        }

        task.resume()

        return task

    }

}
```

This class compares your app version with your app store version and reports it as a bool value.
You can call `AppStoreCheck.isUpdateAvailable` and add the function through a bool value.