# iOS-How to keep update Sqlite Database with new version

Tags: ios, sqlite

In my new version add some new table and some new fields is existing .How to save to crashed and keep update with new version.

Answer (score 0):

When you application working with sqlite, before insert/update data in to table you can check that new row is already exist on table or not. if not you can add it new row in existing table.

Same way Table already exist or not you can check before any operation in table.Bashed on that you can create new table or update in existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some logics to maintain the version updates.

First in your new version, check the **code(Xcode) version** number with the **App Store version** by using this code, refer [check current app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore). (Apple api is available)

If the version mismatches, then you have to update the database and get all the datas from server whichever needed for new version.

This process you have to check in **appdelegate**.

**Note:** Instead of api call, you can store the version number in the database, and compare the Xcode version.