# Check if my tvOS app has a new version available on the App Store

Tags: tvos

I'm trying the detect whether an update is available in my Apple TV app, then show the user that an update is available.

There's a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25210143/600753) for detecting this in an iOS app, but this is not working for tvOS.

Does anyone know a way to do this for tvOS?

Comment: I thought AppleTV apps downloaded updates automatically.

Comment: by default, yes, but this can be disabled by users

Comment: How is that solution you linked to not working exactly? It does return the same information for an Apple TV application. Make sure you're using `https://` and not `http://`.

Comment: Ah, yes, but it returns the information for the iOS app, but not the tvOS app. In my case our iOS app and tvOS app share a bundle ID which is the recommended approach.