# Any proper method to notify user within app if newer version of app available in App Store iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to notify user, if newer version of my app available on app store.So i used below URL to validate current version and existing version of my app

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=APPLEID

I got repose like this

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

Sometimes i am getting proper repose,But sometime not.Is there any alternative to achieve this feature in iOS app

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion
or you can use this update Manager 

https://gist.github.com/fahadjamal/c6ee03e790c1b3c22d4f04fc5a09ccb0

Answer (score 1):

Use `Harpy` library to get update when new version available to download.

Find sample project , usage and installation in github link

[Link for download harpy library](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy)

You can get it by `Cocoapods` or adding files to your project

Comment: Let me try this library

Comment: Let me know the status after implemented

Comment: This also not working,I am getting like this

[Harpy]: storeURL: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.appname
2017-03-01 17:40:17.737808 appname[2798:957080] [Harpy]: JSON Results: {
    resultCount = 0;
    results =     (
    );
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking app id you can compare bundleId to notify user new version available to download.

You can try this :

```
-(void) checkForNewVersion{

    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if(data != nil)
    {

        NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){

            NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];

            NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

            if ([appStoreVersion compare:currentVersion options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                // Alert View

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: already i tried this method,But sometimes i am not getting value using this URL http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=AppleID

Comment: You can use` Harpy` : this module trigger a UIAlertView when a new version of your app is available on the App Store.

Comment: Harpy also not working,I am getting like this

[Harpy]: storeURL: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.appname
2017-03-01 17:40:17.737808 appname[2798:957080] [Harpy]: JSON Results: {
    resultCount = 0;
    results =     (
    );
}