# iOS application loading from the AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way to know in my app when it was opened from the AppStore? and also was updated?

I need to know how can i debug this or better yet simulate the opening of the app from the store.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by opening app from app store ?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the App Store app triggered the start of your app (as opposed to, say starting the app via Finder or Spotlight)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `openUrlMethod` to findout whether app is opened from appstore or not.

Below is the the method in `AppDelegate` that will be called when app opened from any other app.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
//Get URL Scheme here from url.scheme and compare whether it matches with default URLScheme of appstore or not

}
```

To find out whether app is already **UpToDate** or not, Get the app version from bundle and get the app version in AppStore and compare.

Here is the link to [Check If App has new version or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the app was opened for the first time.

In the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` method in your `AppDelegate` you can test some persistent flag:

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "wasOpenedBefore") {
    //the app is opened for the first time - do what you need
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "wasOpenedBefore")
}
```

The value will be there as long as the app is installed. If user deletes it and installs again you will see it as a first time opening. Basically, it satisfies your requirements to know if the app was opened after being downloaded from AppStore.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way that i can open my app using the bundleID from another app?

Comment: @DudikBenShimol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone. If my answer helped you, please, accept it. Thanks.