# Does Apple allows force update to newer version for iOS Applications?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

*Does Apple allows any category of iOS application (i.e games or any type) to force users for new version update, **without update later or cancel button** (if user don't want to do or intend to do it later)*

***Apple used to reject applications on such scenarios, Please correct me if I am wrong.***

> An application which currenly forced me to update is as follows:
> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/farmville-2-country-escape/id824318267?mt=8

Please find screenshot attached.

[image: farmville 2 have only update option in case of new version]

> After new version release whenever I open this application, it has only one button which says **"Upgrade Now"**.
>
> I am **unable to use** until I click upgrade button.
>
> I am wondering is it mistake on Apple review process or is it really
> allowed to do now?

Comment: You need to implement it.. for example your app on startup should verify if there are newer versions and then locks. But if you didn't implement something on your current published app, this version can't show this dialog to users.

Comment: I believe apple always leaves the choice to the user whether to update the app or not. i.,e there is no force update from apple itself. Either you can write the logic to track the updates and ask the user to update or you can go for third parties like https://github.com/emotality/ATAppUpdater, https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy... to handle the newer version update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore Check this link

Answer (score 0):

This process never really went through the apple verification process.
The logic for this probably is...

-) On launch check for update

-) If a update exists, show prompt and lock the application

If the application was being reviewed, then the reviewer never saw such scenario. I am pretty sure if the reviewer saw such locking mechanism, they would simply reject the application. Either way if you really want to force a user to a specific version, this seems to be the best way forward.