# how does siren library get the current app store version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, updatecheck

https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Our client's vendor used this library to push update alerts to the user.
Our app is a LOB app hosted in the client's enterprise application page.

I want to know how the current app store version is obtained and checked

Answer (score 1):

It uses iTunes API. Check https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren/blob/master/Sources/Siren.swift, particularily `performVersionCheck()` and `iTunesURLFromString()`

Comment: you could also may be interested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore