# How to send notification to all users when new version is uploaded in appstore?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to send notification to all user when application is release in appstore without using push notifcation.Is there any method I can notify to my users.

Comment: Hi.. I have added a functionality to check version on device and compare it with version on appstore. If version on device is lesser that the one on appstore then show a pop up to update app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if my app has a new version on AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to send notification to alert user with out APNS or socket (backround running ). with out APNS, you can check only when the app is opening and call an apple API  or your api for getting latest app version and then you can trigger a local notification .

Comment: Thanks allot for your help.