# Check if my app has a new version on iOS Testflight?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to manually check if there are new updates for my app while the user is in it, and prompt him to download the new version. Can I do this by checking the version of my app in the iOS Testflight?

NB: App is not in the App Store. An authorized user can download and use the app through test flight.

Comment: What is the issue.. **How to show prompt?** or **How to check version of app??**

Comment: Suppose there is a new version available in the testflight of the specifi app. Now I wan to show a text to the user that a new version is available and allow him to update.

Comment: try http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=YourBundleIdentifier

Comment: @manishsharma93 link is not working. It downloads a text a file.

Comment: @ShaafiShovon It will return all the details about your app on App store. You can fetch the required data and show according to your need.

Comment: My app is not in the app store yet. I want to check it against the testflight from where an authorized user can download and use the app.

Comment: @ShaafiShovon You cant check untill your app is not on app store. You cant check same functionality on flightTest. Any other query ??

Comment: you find any solution for this?

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat,Did you solve it?

Comment: sorry bor. No :(

Answer (score 0):

Unlike on the App Store, there doesn't seem to be a way to lookup a TestFlight bundle in a non-authenticated manner.

---

Notice how the [App Store lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore) has no authentication:

- `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.example`

The closest equivalents for TestFlight are:

1. `https://testflight.apple.com/join/TEST_FLIGHT_ID`

   However, you can only see the name of the app and its icon in the HTML.
2. `itms-beta://testflight.apple.com/join/TEST_FLIGHT_ID`

   Eventually hits an endpoint that seems promising, but it hits an authentication endpoint first, and passes along data from the authentication endpoint to the aforementioned endpoint (even for public betas).

Therefore, it doesn't seem like there is a way to publicly query TestFlight to learn about new versions. It seems to require authentication.