# How to detect if a new app version is available on AppStore if .xcodeproj file version is different from AppStore released version?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, version, app-store-connect

I'm developing an already existing project that **is mismatching versions between released app on Apple Store Connect (8.x.x) and .xcodeproj file (21.x.x).**

I was trying to accomplish this based on
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore)

But It can't be done for **itunes API does not return build version or build number. And can't find installed release version from code.** Solution above returns version from .xcodeproj file (21.x.x) in code.

- Is there a way to get corresponding installed version from AppStore
  by code?
- Or, can I jump to release version 21.x.x in the AppStore to match the
  .xcodeproj file version without get into trouble with Apple or
  technically-speaking?

Comment: Apple doesn't care about version numbers. All that matters is that the numbers go up, not down

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand your exact issue but Fastlane allows you to retrieve the current version of the app on App Store Connect (live or not)

http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/app_store_build_number/